# ASP MVC route with parameter in the begin of url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello by default  ASP MVC routes are looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but is it possible to use it in next way with not optional ID:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{id}/{controller}/{action}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 0 }
                );
```

Comment: Have you tried? Should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Just tried:

RoutesRegistration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{id}/{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 0}
);
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
}
```